# How to plot hyperrectangles of scipy.spatial.kdtree

Tags: python, scipy, kdtree, spatial-index, scipy-spatial

Im trying to perform a KD-tree on a set of x,y coordinate pairs for spatial indexing them. I found scipy.spatial.kdtree to perform this quickly. However I can't seem to manage plotting hyperrectangles of the kdtree (Im using matplotlib).

Does anyone know how to fetch the hyperrectangles generated by the algorithm?

Comment: Couldnt attach image, here is my desired output:
[A kd-tree.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Kdtree_2d.svg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> how to fetch the hyperrectangles generated by the algorithm ?

the trick is to generate them as you go along: extend
[wikipedia K-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) with e.g.

```
class Node( namedtuple( "Node",  # aka Box
"level "    # 0 ..
"axis "     # 0 .. Dim
"mid "      # the point with middle x / middle y
"lo hi "    # corners, inbox(p): lo <= p <= hi
"L R "      # left, right Nodes or None
"points "   # if needed / leaves only
)):
...
```

Code to build (no query yet)
might be under [my gists](https://gist.github.com/denis-bz). 
A sample plot:
[image]